# Flask - Path Variables Converted to 'None'

Tags: python, flask, routes

I am building a URL shortener using Flask. I am having trouble with a route converting a path variable to None in a specific case but I cannot explain the behavior.

I have a "shortened" URL with an ID of `VyFVXAR2` in my database. To navigate to the true URL, I have a route (below) for `/<url_id>`. When I navigate to `/VyFVXAR2`, I'm getting a `url_id` value of `None`. What is throwing me for a loop is that `/vyFVXAR2` gives me the proper `url_id` value as does `/VyFVXAR3` or any random assortment of characters.

**Route:**

```
 @app.route('/<string:url_id>')
    def get(url_id):
        print(f'url_id: {url_id}')
        url = Link.get_url_by_id(url_id=url_id)

        return render_template('go.html', url=url)
```

**URL returns:**

/VyFVXAR2

`url_id: None`

/ljasdfo2

`url_id: ljasdfo2`

/VyFVXAR3

`url_id: VyFVXAR3`

/vyFVXAR3

`url_id: vyFVXAR3`

What would explain this behavior?

*Edit:* Just to clarify, I'm having an issue getting the ID from the URL when I navigate to `/VyFVXAR2`. I can get the ID from the URL from any other address (samples above).

*Further Edit:* It is only an issue with Firefox. Chrome and Edge both return the correct id from the path variables.

I think I can close this not because it has been answered but because I can no longer replicate the issue. Just to note, the only change I've made to my code is including the pprint module to format the output of the `request.environ` object. I am running the app locally using Flask's built-in `run` function.

`request.environ` before it started working (it looks like Firefox was feeding the `/None` URI to my app for some reason):

```
{'wsgi.version': (1, 0), 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http', 'wsgi.input': <_io.BufferedReader name=1008>, 'wsgi.errors': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>, 'wsgi.multithread': True, 'wsgi.multiprocess': False, 'wsgi.run_once': False, 'werkzeug.server.shutdown': <function WSGIRequestHandler.make_environ.<locals>.shutdown_server at 0x000001F460DEBE50>, 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Werkzeug/1.0.1', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'PATH_INFO': '/None', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'REQUEST_URI': '/None', 'RAW_URI': '/None', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REMOTE_PORT': 58610, 'SERVER_NAME': '127.0.0.1', 'SERVER_PORT': '5000', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1', 'HTTP_HOST': '127.0.0.1:5000', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS': '1', 'werkzeug.request': <Request 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/None' [GET]>}
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2020 09:20:23] "GET /None HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

`request.environ` after it started working:

```
{   'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',
    'HTTP_HOST': '127.0.0.1:5000',
    'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS': '1',
    'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) '
                       'Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0',
    'PATH_INFO': '/VyFVXAR2',
    'QUERY_STRING': '',
    'RAW_URI': '/VyFVXAR2',
    'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
    'REMOTE_PORT': 63858,
    'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
    'REQUEST_URI': '/VyFVXAR2',
    'SCRIPT_NAME': '',
    'SERVER_NAME': '127.0.0.1',
    'SERVER_PORT': '5000',
    'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
    'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Werkzeug/1.0.1',
    'werkzeug.request': <Request 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/VyFVXAR2' [GET]>,
    'werkzeug.server.shutdown': <function WSGIRequestHandler.make_environ.<locals>.shutdown_server at 0x0000016FD72ABEE0>,
    'wsgi.errors': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>,
    'wsgi.input': <_io.BufferedReader name=752>,
    'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
    'wsgi.multithread': True,
    'wsgi.run_once': False,
    'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
    'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}
```

Comment: I tried your code (with just the print statement) and a return of 'hi', and I"m not able to reproduce the issue. Are you sure everything here is correct and reproducible?

Comment: I am pretty sure. The issue is that the print statement outputs 'url_id: None' when I navigate to /VyFVXAR2 but it returns the correct url_id with anything else. It could be an issue with my machine but it's very odd. Just to clarify further: the route works and the go.html page is rendered. I am having an issue getting the ID from the url.

Comment: Could you post the request logs in the terminal when you visit the URL with Firefox?

Comment: I've edited my post to include the output of Flask's request.environ. I can no longer replicate the issue though despite only adding the pprint module to format the output of that environ object. It could be a fluke on my end; I may never know. It is, however, working at this moment.